# scipy or numpy implementation of coordinate descent algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Is there an implementation of the [coordinate descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) algorithm in scipy or numpy?

I have looked to [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) but I did not find it.

Comment: Ah, never mind. Just realized that "coordinate descent" refers to a specific algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent Hadn't come across the term being used for a specific algorithm before.  I don't believe `scipy.optimize` implements that particular algorithm. Powell's method is similar, but slightly different.

Comment: Thanks Powell seems to be fine for me. I was looking for a simple method because sometimes is important to understand what is happening